# Resolving AngularJS promise returned by Factory function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I have a factory object that has a `getProduct(id)` function as shown below

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('productFactory', ['$http', 'URL', function($http, URL){

        var urlBase = URL.APISERVER;

        //productFactory return object
        var productFactory = {};

        productFactory.getProducts = function(){
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/products/');
        }

        productFactory.getProduct = function(id){
            return $http.get(urlBase + '/products/' + id);
        }
        //return factory object
        return productFactory;
    }]);
```

In my controller I want to resolve the `getProduct(id)` promise. I am resolving this promise in another function `getProduct(id)` where I passed the product id.

```
angular.module('portal')
    .controller('ProductCtrl', ['$stateParams','productFactory', 
      function($stateParams, productFactory){
        //Using 'controller as syntax' in view
        var prod = this;

        //Saves status of promise
        prod.status;

        //Get a single product
        prod.product;

        //Get the product id from stateParams and pass that to
        //productFactory's getProduct(id) function
        var id = $stateParams.id;
        getProduct(id);//THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE 500 ERROR

        //Resolves promise 
        function getProduct(id){
          productFactory.getProduct(id)
            .success(function(product){
              prod.product = product;
            })
            .error(function(error){
              prod.status = 'Unable to load product data' + error.message;
            });
        }


    }]);
```

However, when I invoke `getProduct(id);` in my controller I get `500 error` and that's because I don't yet have access to the `$stateParams.id` when the controller compiles.

I have a list of products. When clicked on a particular product I am redirected to the view of this single product. So far it works with the `500 error`. Any ideas how to fix this issue. My initial idea is to call the `getProduct(id);` in my controller conditionally. I am sure there is a better way to do this.

**UPDATE**

Here is the relevant routing config for this state.

```
.state('products-view', {
  url: '/products/:id',
  templateUrl: '/core/products/view.html'
})
```

Comment: Show routing config for that state. No reason `$stateParams` shouldn't be available assuming `id` is in url

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated my question.

Comment: if there is a valid id in url should all be working fine. What is url being used for request itself in dev tools network? Is it showing the correct ID or something like `undefined`? Does API work if opened in browser window by itself with a valid id in url?

Comment: @charlietfl yes there is a valid url in the link. The url is used to request a json file from a perl backend (This is temporary as we don't yet have a RESTful endpoint for this resource). The `http` request returns the json document but I still get a `500` error in the Chrome dev tools console.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like the following to resolve http requests using ui-router.

```
$stateProvider
    // nested list with custom controller
    .state('home.list', {
        url: '/list/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
        resolve:{
          // Inject services or factories here to fetch 'posts'
          posts:function($http, $stateParams){
            return $http.get('//jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + ($stateParams.id || 1));
          }
        },
        // resolved 'posts' get injected into controller
        controller: function(posts, $scope){
          $scope.posts = posts.data;
        }
    })
```

You can dependency inject `productFactory` instead of `$http` like I did.  The `posts` key specified in `resolve` can be dependency injected into the controller specified as a function or as a string.

Comment: I wanted to try this implementation initially but I think is much cleaner to resolve the promise in a controller.  So far I've I solved this issue by calling `getProduct(id)` when the id is not `undefined`